# Apache2 crashed Ubuntu 12 Desktop

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, lamp

I had recently installed Apache2 through Terminal(on Ubuntu 12 Desktop), it was running fine. However, when I started my system today I was unable to login.

The difference that I noticed was :
- The logon screen displayed Guest account 
- And on the task-bar(menu-bar) on the top it was displaying my account name, however was unable to logon to Guest account as well.

**Does Apache2/LAMP need Server OS as a mandatory requirement or they can run normally on Desktop OS as well?**

Need to get my Ubuntu OS back up and running.

**NOTE :** I have dual booted my system(Primary - Windows 7; Secondary - Ubuntu 12 Desktop)

Any Suggestion/Advice/Troubleshooting Solution would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LAMPP does not need a server OS, it should run on a desktop system just fine. Try logging in via terminal (press Ctrl+Alt+F2 to get there). There you can uninstall programs with `apt-get` or `aptitude`.

Note: if Ctrl+Alt+F2 does not work, try it with other F-keys.

Comment: Hi Paukku, Thanks was able to atleast login. However all features(sidebar, taskbar,  terminal) seems to be disabled.